# Could a soul from the Soulmonger be restored in the ToA campaign after this event?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, tomb-of-annihilation, soul

Assume some soul was sucked into the Soulmonger.

This event could happen with this soul, when it is inside:

> The Atropal could eat it

Is it possible to resurrect a soul after this event happens? Maybe with a Wish spell or the Divine Intervention cleric feature?

Comment: Ok I'll tweak the question wording then. Not that it's a big deal, but for future reference comments don't have spoiler tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Resurrection becomes impossible after this event

Note what is said on page 7 of the adventure, under ["Soul Devouring"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/introduction#SoulDevouring):

> A roll of 1 indicates that the soul was devoured by the atropal. A creature whose soul is devoured in this horrific manner can't be returned to life by any means, including divine intervention.

This is very clear. Nothing, not even Wish or Divine Intervention will help in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The only way a soul devoured by the atropal can be restored is if the DM makes an exception to the rules by using DM fiat as spelled out in the DMG.  But there is no way to restore a soul and remain in conformity to the adventure as published.

That said I did notice that this fate does appear to contradict another question regarding the fate of a soul that is consumed by a lich's phylactery.

[Does a soul consumed by a lich's phylactery avoid the afterlife?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110368/does-a-soul-consumed-by-a-lichs-phylactery-avoid-the-afterlife?rq=1)